# Dynamic template in directive based on attributes?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Ive seen a bunch of questions pretty similar to this, but I'm new to Angular so they aren't *quite* making sense. Here's my sitaution:

I have a directive defined:

```
robus.directive("titlebar", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    scope: { title: '@title' },
    template: "<header class='bar-title'><h1 class='title'>{{title}}</h1></header>",
    replace: true
  }
});
```

I use this directive like this:

```
<titlebar title="{{workout.name}}"></titlebar>
```

Ideally, I want to add optional attributes into this, like:

```
<titlebar title="{{workout.name}}" editButton="true" closeButton="true"></titlebar>
```

How do I handle these in the `template` definition? I've been reading about a `$compile()` function that I need to override, but haven't been clear on how to do so. The templates are just simple strings, so I feel like I can just do them inline versus referencing them as separate files.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make them accessible within the directive by adding them to the scope statement, just as you have the title. Then add the buttons to the template, and conditionalize them like so:

```
robus.directive("titlebar", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
      scope: { title: '@title', edit: '@editButton', cancel: '@cancelButton' },
      template: "<header class='bar-title'><h1 class='title'>{{title}}</h1><span ng-show='edit'>Edit</span><span ng-show='cancel'>Cancel</span></header>",
    replace: true
  }
});

<titlebar title="{{workout.name}}" edit-button="true" cancel-button="false"></titlebar>
```

Note that it's editButton in the directive and edit-button in the HTML; there's a built-in conversion from hyphenated to camel-case that will bite you if you're not aware of it.

Also, I recommend the use of transclude here, as I think it will read a bit more cleanly:

```
robus.directive("titlebar", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
      scope: { edit: '@editButton', cancel: '@cancelButton' },
      template: "<header class='bar-title'><h1 class='title' ng-transclude></h1><span ng-show='edit'>Edit</span><span ng-show='cancel'>Cancel</span></header>",
    transclude: true,
      replace: true
  }
});

<titlebar edit-button="true" cancel-button="false">{{workout.name}}</titlebar>
```

Comment: Ah, that's great. Makes sense that you can use `ng-show` in the template - didn't even think to use them!